# Full RelayCommand in F#?

Tags: f#, relaycommand

I am new to F#. As a learning experiment, I am rewriting a C# application in pure F#. How can the "RelayCommand" , RelayCommand, of C# be written in F# ?

Any help is most appreciated.

TIA

As requested, this is the RelayCommand I've been using in C#. :( It seems overly complicated. (There must surely be a simpler one!).

```
    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly WeakAction<T> _execute;

        private readonly WeakFunc<T, bool> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }

            _execute = new WeakAction<T>(execute);

            if (canExecute != null)
            {
                _canExecute = new WeakFunc<T, bool>(canExecute);
            }
        }


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                }
            }

            remove
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                }
            }
        }


        
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {

            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (_canExecute.IsStatic || _canExecute.IsAlive)
            {
                if (parameter == null && typeof(T).IsValueType)

                {
                    return _canExecute.Execute(default(T));
                }

                if (parameter == null || parameter is T)
                {
                    return (_canExecute.Execute((T)parameter));
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

       
        public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var val = parameter;


            if (CanExecute(val)
                && _execute != null
                && (_execute.IsStatic || _execute.IsAlive))
            {
                if (val == null)
                {

                    if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
                    {
                        _execute.Execute(default(T));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ReSharper disable ExpressionIsAlwaysNull
                        _execute.Execute((T)val);
                        // ReSharper restore ExpressionIsAlwaysNull
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _execute.Execute((T)val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public class WeakFunc<TResult>
    {
     private Func<TResult> _staticFunc;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the <see cref="MethodInfo" /> corresponding to this WeakFunc's
        /// method passed in the constructor.
        /// </summary>
        protected MethodInfo Method
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a value indicating whether the WeakFunc is static or not.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsStatic
        {
            get
            {
                return _staticFunc != null;
            }
        }


        public virtual string MethodName
        {
            get
            {
                if (_staticFunc != null)
                {

                    return _staticFunc.Method.Name;
                }


                return Method.Name;
            }
        }


        protected WeakReference FuncReference
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected WeakReference Reference
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        
        protected WeakFunc()
        {
        }

        
        public WeakFunc(Func<TResult> func)
            : this(target: func?.Target, func: func)
        {
        }

        
        public WeakFunc(object target, Func<TResult> func)
        {

            if (func.Method.IsStatic)
            {
                _staticFunc = func;

                if (target != null)
                {
                    // Keep a reference to the target to control the
                    // WeakAction's lifetime.
                    Reference = new WeakReference(target);
                }

                return;
            }


            Method = func.Method;
            FuncReference = new WeakReference(func.Target);

            Reference = new WeakReference(target);
        }

        public virtual bool IsAlive
        {
            get
            {
                if (_staticFunc == null
                    && Reference == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (_staticFunc != null)
                {
                    if (Reference != null)
                    {
                        return Reference.IsAlive;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                return Reference.IsAlive;
            }
        }

        public object Target
        {
            get
            {
                if (Reference == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return Reference.Target;
            }
        }

        
        protected object FuncTarget
        {
            get
            {
                if (FuncReference == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return FuncReference.Target;
            }
        }

       
        public TResult Execute()
        {
            if (_staticFunc != null)
            {
                return _staticFunc();
            }

            var funcTarget = FuncTarget;

            if (IsAlive)
            {
                if (Method != null
                    && FuncReference != null
                    && funcTarget != null)
                {
                    return (TResult)Method.Invoke(funcTarget, null);
                }

            }

            return default(TResult);
        }

        
        public void MarkForDeletion()
        {
            Reference = null;
            FuncReference = null;
            Method = null;
            _staticFunc = null;

        }
    }
```

As a newbie to F#, how can this be implemented? How does F# deal with "WeakAction"?

Thank you.

Comment: There are many implementations of RelayCommand in C#.  Can you link to the one you want to port?

Comment: Please provide a minimum example in C# of what you want o implement in F# https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.   It's unlikely you'll need to use the command pattern at all.

Comment: @Foole The RelayCommand I've been using is now posted with question. It seems overly complicated...There must surely be a simplier one using WeakActions?  Thanks.

Comment: @KoenigLear I am learning F# from the bottom up. Can you point me in the direction of how to write a UI in MVVM style without using a RelayCommand? As a beginner, it seems the ViewModel must have some sort of commanding? Or is there a better strategy then MVVM with F#??

Comment: @AlanWayne Have a look at Model-View-Update more natural in functional programming see Elmish WPF https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md. It actually covers Commands use. Probably easier if you start from scratch tough rather than translating.

Comment: @KoenigLear Coming from a FoxPro/C# background, your suggestion of reading Elmish WPF is very appreciated. It throws most of what I know upside down...quite refreshing :) Good advice. Thanks.